# Laravel has Many with a where on upper model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure

---

**Turn**
id

**OrderPayment**
id
turn_id
invoice_id

**OrderInvoice**
id
order_id

**Order**
id
canceled
merged

---

What I want to do is get the `OrderPayments` where `Order` is not canceled neither merged

Now I have the following code in turn

```
class Turn{

    public function orderPayments(){
        return $this->hasMany('OrderPayment');
    }
}
```

How should I do to get only the payments that are related to a `Order` with the

```
 ->where('canceled' < '0000-00-00 00:00:10 ')
 ->where('merged'  < '0000-00-00 00:00:10 ')
```

Thank you so much!!

---

**EDIT Updating with the relations I actually have**

In `OrderPayment` I have the function

```
public function invoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Invoice');
}
```

In `OrderInvoice` I have the function

```
public function order(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Order');
}
```

This is the code I'm trying on `Turn` is the following

> ```
> public function orderPayments(){
>     return OrderPayment::whereHas('invoice',function($query){
>        $query->whereHas('order',function($query){
>            $query->where('canceled','<','0000-00-00 00:00:01')
>                  ->where('merged','<','0000-00-00 00:00:01');
>        });
>     })->where('turn_id','=',$this->id)->get();
> }
> ```

And I get the following exception

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::order()`

Answer (score 1):

You need `whereHas`:

```
$payments = OrderPayment::whereHas('invoice', function ($q) {
   $q->whereHas('order', function ($q) {
      $q->where('canceled', '=', '0000-00-00')
        ->where('merged', '=', '0000-00-00');
   });
})->get();
```

As a side note I would change those columns to `nullable` and search for `whereNull('canceled')` etc.

Comment: Hey, really thanks for you answer, however I get this error when trying that ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Order()``` I assume orderInvoices is the method to get the invoice of the payment right? in my case the function is called invoice, so then I assume that order is the method on molde OrderInvoice to get the order? It is called order

Comment: Just updated the question with some more info, I added the relationship methods I have in each Model and what I'm trying now thanks to your answer

Comment: Any idea why does that happen?

Comment: Your code is really hard to read. You have `OrderInvoice` model, then you refer to `Invoice` in the relation on `OrderPayment`.. If your relations are correct, then this error can't show up. I edited my asnwer with `invoice`, but that's what you tried...

Comment: yeah, in the relationship funcion I remove the ```Order``` part... do you think I may be the problem?

Comment: Well you refer the `Model` class name there, so it definitely is a problem. Should be `belongsTo('OrderInvoice')` if that's the class name.

Comment: I have a class called ```Order```and that ```belongsTo()```is ok, in fact I have ```Order```, ``OrderInvoice```, and ```OrderPayment``` like a cascade, and finall ```Turn``` that is a many to many to ```OrderPayment```